# urllib2.URLError exception not getting caught

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I have the following code block:

```
def bar( self ):
    ...
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        if (e.errno == errno.ECONNRESET and retryCount < MAX_RETRY_COUNT):
            time.sleep( 10 )
            self.bar()
        else:
            raise
```

Which when run may sometimes result in the server throwing a `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>`. But this exception is not getting caught by the `except` block:

```
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 123, in bar
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

What is causing the exception to not get caught? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it the same code? Your code has `( req )` whereas the traceback has `(req)`.

Comment: Code got slightly formatted. But yes, same relevant 'code'. Fixed what you pointed to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Have you added print statements to check whether it's not caught? It could be that the if statement is false and it's simply being raised again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it is getting caught:

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    if (e.errno == errno.ECONNRESET and retryCount < MAX_RETRY_COUNT):
        time.sleep( 10 )
        self.bar()
    else:
        raise
```

Notice the `raise` function at the end of the code sample. This will re-raise the same exception if your if statement evaluates to `False`, which appears to be very likely the case. Try replacing `raise` with `print("IF STATEMENT FALSE")` to see this.

Comment: This did turn out to be case. Apparently, errno does not get set in this scenario. That is the condition that failed. Thanks!